# ssh to a bridged VM Guest on LAN

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

i have a machine with ubuntu 16.04 x64 & virtualbox 5.0 installed as VM Host. then create a VM Guest (debian 8 x86) and set to bridged adapter.

the VM Host can ssh the VM guest by ip. but the others on Lan can not:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.106 port 22: Connection refused

ping VM guest is ok on both VM host and the others.

if setting to NAT adapter and port forward ssh is also fine

where would the problem be?

edit>
to make it clear:

- there's 2 real machines in Lan(192.168.0.x) : 101 & 130.
- a VM is created on 130 with bridged adapter, and the ip is 106.
- 130 can ssh 106, but 101 can not
- both 130 and 101 can ping 106
- if change VM to NAT adapter, and forward port 22 to 130:2222, 101 can ssh to the VM through 130:2222, seems that ssh works fine on VM
- question is how to ssh a bridged VM on Lan?

Comment: If u are trying for connecting to the gust machine through NAT connection check this post http://wiki.workassis.com/virtualbox-ssh-between-host-and-guest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be a dhcp router issue.

the router donot specified the gate way ip caused this problem